# Converting dxGrid to cxGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I'm converting existing database driven application from D7 to D2009, therefore I won't be able to use dxGrids anymore. Is there any automatic way to convert dxGrid components to cxGrids? If not, what would you suggest me in order to gain time converting them manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a issue on the Dev Express site that address this issue
[www.devexpress.com/issue=CQ59375](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=CQ59375)

Excerpt:

> In brief, you should perform the
>   following steps to convert your
>   current project:
>
> 1) Install both versions of the
>   ExpressQuantumGrid (v3 and v6) for
>   Delphi6; 
> 2) Convert your old grid's
>   layout to the latest product version
>   (please refer to the "Converting to
>   ExpressQuantumGrid" topic in the
>   ExpressQuantumGrid's documentation to
>   find more information on this
>   subject); 
> 3) Adjust your code to use
>   the latest product version; 
> 4) Install
>   the latest version of the
>   ExpressQuantumGrid (v6) for Delphi
>   2007; 5) Use the converted project in
>   Delphi 2007.

From the help file that they refer to:

> ExpressQuantumGrid provides an Import
>   dialog at design time for importing
>   settings from third-party grid
>   controls and converting them to the
>   native properties of the
>   ExpressQuantumGrid.  Three types of
>   grid components can be imported to
>   ExpressQuantumGrid:
>
> · ExpressQuantumGrid3 (TdxDBGrid) and
>   ExpressQuantumGrid3 Layout
>   (TdxDBGridLayout)
>   · standard TDBGrid
>   · W2W InfoPowerGrid 3000 (TwwDBGrid)

Answer (score 2):

ExpressQuantumGrid by VCL may have the [migration support](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/51016.aspx) you need.